# Finding post with multiple tags

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for posts with multiple tags and have came up with the following code, is there a better way to do this or is this fine?

My MySQL database has three tables posts, tags, and post_tags

- posts: id|body
- tags: tag|mode
- post_tags: postid|tag

(Each tag on eachvpost gets its own column)

```
     if(isset($_GET["query"])){
    $query = trim($_GET['query']);
    $searchs = explode(",", $query);
    $results = DB::query('SELECT * FROM post_tags WHERE tag=:tag', array(':tag' => $searchs[0]));
    $posts = "";
    foreach($results as $result){
        $pass = true;
        foreach($searchs as $search){
            if(DB::query('SELECT * FROM post_tags WHERE post_id=:postid AND 
tag=:tag', array(':postid' => $result['post_id'], ':tag' => $search))){

            }else{
                $pass = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($pass){
            $posts .= $result['post_id'];
        }
    }
    echo $posts;
}
```

My main worry is if a tag has millions of posts won't it be looping through millions of things which doesn't sound efficient.

Edit:

```
if(isset($_GET["query"])){
    $query = trim($_GET['query']);
    $searchs = explode(",", $query);
    $dataquery = "SELECT * FROM posts AS P
INNER JOIN post_tags AS PT
    ON PT.postid = P.id
INNER JOIN tags AS T
    ON PT.tag = T.tag";

    foreach($searchs as $search){
        $dataquery .= " WHERE T.tag = :tag";
    }

    $posts = DB::query($dataquery, array(':tag' => $searchs));

    echo sizeof($posts);
```

Query Method

```
     public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);
    if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is why table JOINs exist. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html you should only select the tables that have a join to the tag you're searching for.

Comment: Use `?` instead of `:tag`

Comment: and not `WHERE t = f WHERE t= d` but `WHERE t = f OR t = d`

Comment: @ezw I don't get all the letters and where you're getting them from

Comment: We're basically telling MySQL to retrieve the table `posts` but we are going to name it as `P` for this query statement... thus SELECT * FROM posts AS `P`

Comment: @ezw Don't i want to use an AND since I want post that contains all the tags not just if it contains one of the tags

Comment: why ask again (oh 3rd time actually)? why ignore the advice from the last time you asked?

Comment: @rtfm That was a different question the other one was for the idea more so this one is more how to improve this (Because it is again a different question, why else would I make a new question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select item with multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980522/select-item-with-multiple-tags)

Comment: Well, use AND if you need to, I'm just providing code for your solution. Up to you to tweak it

Comment: @Dan I've updated my solution for a dynamic WHERE clause

Comment: Surely 'its own row' ??

Comment: And see IN() - there are some examples of how to use IN() in a secure manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts AS P
            INNER JOIN post_tags AS PT
                ON PT.postid = P.id
            INNER JOIN tags AS T
                ON PT.tag = T.tag
        WHERE " . str_repeat(" T.tag = ? AND", count($searchs));

// The actual SQL you will be using. We are removing the last ' AND' from the sql
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);

// The correct way
$posts = DB::query($sql, $searchs);
```

Comment: Do I leave it as a ? or am I suppose to use the array to replace it or something?

Comment: I am using PDO I added the my query method into my main question, the page won't load when using this

Comment: Update your PHP implementation with this query

Comment: @Dan Look at my solution, is that how you are calling the query?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls show your tables.
Or you can add relation ship in your table and use query sql like this

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
left join post_tags pt on pt.post_id =  p.id
left join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.tag = '$searchs[0]'
```

i think t.tag like %$searchs[0]%  is better. and if you more search keywords you can use

```
WHERE t.tag = '$searchs[0]' OR t.tag = '$searchs[1]'
```

Or you can search with in post title

```
WHERE t.tag = '$searchs[0]' OR p.post_title = '$searchs[0]'
```

Comment: The search can have more than one tag, for example they might search "car,blue" or even "car,blue,cheap,used" Would this support that? Also what is p in 'posts p' where do you get the p

Comment: The `p` here is the same as the `P` in my solution. Just a name for the query that references the table it's set to represent

Comment: His query is the same as my query... just add as many WHERE clauses as you need. If you're going to have a dynamic amount, than you'd have to dynamically build your WHERE query